# getopt() and detecting a missing "option"

Tags: c, getopt

When using `getopt` or `getopt_long` to parse a commandline for a set of required options, how does one determine that a required "option" is missing or not specified? I've scoured all the docs and man pages and cannot find a clear answer.

In running a simple test stub with a missing -b option, `getopt_long` always returns -1, `opterr` is 1, and `optarg` is null - just like a normal/successful parsing of all required options. My short_options = "n:t:b:".

Comment: The only obvious solution is to examine argc for required number of options. getopt/getopt_long does not seem to have a feature to specify required options or to validate them.

Comment: I'd use flags in the option parsing "switch" statement (one case per option letter), set them to true/1 whenever that case is reached. Then after all option parsing check whether the required flag(s) is/are set.